# If Previous Content Div is Open, Close It and Open the Next (Plain JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I have this simple dropdown faq system, I only want one content div to be open at a time, so I tried to use an if / else condition, but I can only make it work halfway.

1. I'm checking if the content div next to the trigger div has class is-visible — if not, add that class (this works)
2. But if the previous content div has (contains) class is-visible, I want to remove it, so only one content div is open at a time.

I've tried so many different conditions but I think I'm overcomplexifying it, this should be simple enough right?

https://jsfiddle.net/notuhm05/1/

```
var faqTrigger = document.querySelectorAll('.mm-faq-trigger');
for (var i = 0; i < faqTrigger.length; i++) {
    faqTrigger[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (!this.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('is-visible');
      } else if (this.previousElementSibling.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('is-visible');
      } else {
        console.log("doesn't work");
      }
    });
}
```

Would greatly appreciate some pointers here! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

- Toggle the class `is-visible` on the clicked node
- Iterate through all triggers and remove the class `is-visible` if the id of the `href` tag does not match the clicked nodes id. **NOTE:** I had to add an id property to the trigger `href` tag like `<a id="1" href="#" class="mm-faq-trigger">Trigger</a>`
- Source Code:

  ```
  var faqTrigger = document.querySelectorAll('.mm-faq-trigger');
  for (var i = 0; i < faqTrigger.length; i++) {
      faqTrigger[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('is-visible');

      for (var i = 0; i < faqTrigger.length; i++) {
          var trigger = faqTrigger[i];
          if (trigger.nextElementSibling !== null && trigger.id !== this.id)  {
              trigger.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('is-visible');
         }    
      }    
  });
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you, it works great, but just a question, is it necessary to use ID's in this type of scenario, or is it just easier that way? I ask because I'm trying to work around using ID's for the most part.

Comment: With this solution you need to somehow uniquely identify the trigger elements. You could try to find the innerHTML of the <p> elements and use this as identifier.

Comment: I ended up removing the ID, so instead I now address the href directly and give them different numbers, like <a href="#1"  — then I used trigger.href instead of trigger.id. It works just the same https://jsfiddle.net/k7dz5qg6/1/ is that a decent solution or?

Comment: i think thats a decent solution. Just remeber that the hashtag in href provided in URL will "jump" to that element. But thats anyhow something you might want. Here is a solution which works without adding additional IDs or whatever. Just replaec the if clause in the for loop:
      if (trigger.parentElement !== null && this.parentElement !== null
        && trigger.parentElement.innerHTML !== this.parentElement.innerHTML)  {
            trigger.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('is-visible');
       }

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks a lot, you've been a great help, I learned a lot from this!